# Database import error (version?)

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm working on a project and I have a problem with my backup: when I try to import the file on phpmyadmin, I have multiple errors due to syntax...

I've already use this backup before and she always worked fine.

Maybe this is a version compatibility error? How to resolve that?

Example of error:

2 errors found during the analysis.

A quote ' was expected. (Near ' ' at position 42621 )
9 values ​​were expected , but 8 were found . ( Near " (" at position 42204 )

Thanks

Comment: You should give us the statement (most likely an insert) that causes the problem, else we can't help much. And the table structure would be great too.

Comment: INSERT INTO `block_custom` VALUES (1,'&copy;<?php print date(\'Y\'); ?> dolphin-scooters.com | <a href=\"http://www.example.com\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"Powered by example \">example </a>','Copyright','php_code'),(2,'<p><div class=\"fb-like-box\" data-href=\"https://www.example.com/\" data-width=\"200\" 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''<p><div class=\"fb-like-box\" data-href=\"https://www.example.com/' at line 1

Structure of block_custom:
BID, body, info, format

Comment: What phpMyAdmin versions are you using for the export and import?

Answer (score 0):

I've remplaced the \' by '' and it works!